# Configure Auto-Number with initials related to another object

Tags: apex, code

I have an object called `Project` where stored the name of the project and its key, respectively:

`My Project Name`,  `MPN`

Then I have a direct child object called `Sprint` followed by `Issue` where I have a auto-number field and I need to select the project/ sprint related to it.

**How could I customize my auto-number value based on the project related to it?**
In other words:

**Issue 1**
`Project Name:` Sample Project Here
`Project Key:` SPH
`Issue Name:` SPH-0001

**Issue 2**
`Project Name:` Another Project There
`Project Key:` APT
`Issue Name:` APT-0001

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Once configured, an auto-number field will generate auto-numbers in specified format with defined prefix. [You can change the format](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_field_attributes.htm&language=en_US#Auto-NumberFormattingExamples), but it will affect only records created after the field change.

Possible solution of your problem could be a formula field that generate a text   prefix depending on the related object key/name.

Answer (score 0):

Create an autonumber field with the 4 digit number.  In a separate, editable 'Issue Name' text field populate the project reference and the autonumber output either via a workflow rule or an Apex trigger.

Example: Autonumber value = 1024, project initals = SPH ==> the 'Issue Name' field will hold SPH-1024.